# Can't install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation, usb-installation

I have managed to create a USB boot of Ubuntu 16.04 and can access it in the "Try Ubuntu..." option. Each time I try to install Ubuntu alongside windows 10 the laptop reboots and it's back to square 1.
I have checked the advanced options but the only option there is "back".
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: You may be having a hardware problem.  You can start out diagnosis by checking your ram.  You can do this using your Live USB media by holding down the `left shift` key during boot.  Then navigate the menus to the `test memory` option.

Comment: Does it seem to go through the install process? .. it may be that Windows 10 is "repairing" the boot loader causing it to overwrite grub and boot back directly into windows even tho Ubuntu is installed. Check to see if you have additional partitions on the drive now. I have a dual boot on a laptop but its older and doesn't have UEFI so if yours is a newer one with UEFI that could also be an issue.

Comment: @L. D. James tried the memory test and all this passed.  But still have the same issue.

Comment: @John Orion I have an old laptop too.  I will check the partitions and see what's happening there.